# Joomla: Importance of pass by reference

Tags: php, joomla

What's different between

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
```

And

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

In Joomla documents used from `& JFactory::getUser();` What's the matter?
Can I use `$user = JFactory::getUser();` instead of `& JFactory::getUser();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
```

note :: should only be used to access static functions.

```
$user = &JFactory::getUser();
```

Which means the value is return by reference to the function, not a copy of the value, but can only be used that way if the function was defined that way.

Answer (score 0):

I actually prefer using without the pass by reference. I think that code is rather outdated Joomla 1.5 code. You probably won't see it anywhere in core code anymore. I also know that in php 5.3 there are some depreciations around pass by reference and it throws a fatal error in php 5.4 (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)